# Jquery Slim Scroll and Angular JS, How to fix scroll at bottom of div?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to make kind of chat web app.
For UX, I want to fix slimscroll bottom of div.
[image]

To do, I wrote my code like this in HTML,

```
<div class="ibox-content" slim-scroll>
     <div ng-repeat="chat in chats track by $index">
         <p>{{chat}}</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

and I declared angularjs directive like this.

```
function slimScroll($timeout){
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
           boxHeight: '@'
       },
       link: function(scope, element) {
           $timeout(function(){
               element.slimscroll({
                   height: '75vh',
                   railOpacity: 0.9,
                   scrollTo: element.scrollHeight,
                   start: 'bottom'
               });
           });
       }
   };
}
```

But I think, `scrollTo: element.scrollHeight,`  doesn't work. What I should do? Is any idea to fix it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach will work - having read the [documentation](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) for Jquery Slim Scroll, I think you will need to call `element.slimscroll` each time you get a new chat message, not just on the initial load.

One way of doing this could be to allow your slim scroll directive to take an array. You could $watch this array to see if its length changes, then you could call scrollTo on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Element returns the `angular.element` object. You need `element[0]` to get the native element.

```
function slimScroll($timeout){
   return {
       restrict: 'A',
       scope: {
           boxHeight: '@'
       },
       link: function(scope, element) {
           $timeout(function(){
               element.slimscroll({
                   height: '75vh',
                   railOpacity: 0.9,
                   scrollTo: element[0].scrollHeight,
                   start: 'bottom'
               });
           });
       }
   };
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work anyway. I think I should find another way